# upload greater than 5TB object to google cloud storage bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, storage

The max size limit for a single object upload is 5TB. How does one do a backup of a larger single workload? Say - I have a single file that is 10TB or more - that needs to be backed up to cloud storage?

Also, a related question - if the 10 TB is spread across multiple files (each file is less than 5TB) in a single folder, that shouldn't affect anything correct? A single object can't be greater than 5TB, but there isn't a limit on the actual bucket size. Say a folder containing 3 objects equal to 10TB, that upload will be automatically split across multiple buckets (console or gsutil upload)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are right. [The current limit on the size for individual objects is 5 TB](https://cloud.google.com/storage/quotas#objects). In this way you might split your file.

About the limitation on the Total Bucket size, there [is no limit documented](https://cloud.google.com/storage/quotas#buckets) on this. Actually, in the overview says ["Cloud Storage provides worldwide, highly durable object storage that scales to exabytes of data."](https://cloud.google.com/storage).
You might take a look into the [best practices](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/best-practices) of GCS.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look over http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~dstromberg/chunkup.html ?

I wrote it to backup to SRB, which is a sort of precursor to Google and Amazon bucketing.  But chunkup itself doesn't depend on SRB or any other form of storage.

```
Usage: /usr/local/etc/chunkup -c chunkhandlerprog -n nameprefix [-t tmpdir] [-b blocksize]
-c specifies the chunk handling program to handle each chunk, and is required
-n specifies the nameprefix to use on all files created, and is required
-t specifies the temporary directory to write files to, and is optional.  Defaults to $TMPDIR or /tmp
-b specifies the length of files to create, and is optional.  Defaults to 1 gigabyte
-d specifies the number of digits to use in filenames.  Defaults to 5
```

You can see example use of chunkup in http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/Backup.remote.html#SRB

HTH